# C free() function called on static memory (on not dynamically allocated memory)

Tags: c, memory-management, free

What will happen if I call free() with non dynamically allocated pointer as the argument?

E.g

```
some_struct foo;
function(&foo);

void function(some_struct* param){
    free(param);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: _if
the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
behavior is undefined._

Comment: That would compile?  foo is not a pointer.   What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me re write the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's against the rules, so just about anything might happen.  `free()` might print an error message.  The program might crash with a segmentation violation or other memory access error.  The error might be silently ignored.  Or the error might lead to corruption of the malloc/free heap such that an error or crash might happen during some later call to malloc or free.

Comment: If that's the case, is there any way for a piece of code to know if the pointer is pointing to a dynamically allocated memory or static allocated memory?

Comment: @Aizen The only way the code (or the programmer) can "know" is by remembering it itself.  There is nothing like an `is_malloced_pointer(p)` function that will tell you.